# How to get chart data from excel file using apache poi in java?

Tags: java, excel, charts, itext, apache-poi

I have an Excel file that has charts.
I want to read that chart and add that charts to pdf using Java.
How can I do that?

I tried different classes of apache poi like XSSFChart, and XSSFChartData but didn't get anything.

Comment: What Apache POI version used?

Comment: Actually i have used two apache versions in different classes like poi-3.17 and poi-5.2.3 but didn't get anything.

Comment: [XSSFChart](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFChart.html) -> [XDDFChart.getChartSeries](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChart.html#getChartSeries--) -> [XDDFChartData](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.html)

Comment: ... then, dependent of what chart data you got, get axes and series -> [XDDFChartData.getCategoryAxis](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.html#getCategoryAxis--), [XDDFChartData.getValueAxes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.html#getValueAxes--) and  [XDDFChartData.getSeries](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.html#getSeries-int-)